# Why doesn't jquery calculate width correctly before $(window).resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got this script here:

```
$('.search-submit').css('right',($('.container').width()-$('.search-input').width())/2-$('.search-submit').width()-20);
```

and it works great after `$(window).resize()` event, but not on `$(document).ready()` - why? On document.ready it calculates a wrong number, but as soon as I resize my window, it fixes that issue. What could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe width not including margin/padding and after resizing window you remove them?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have been seeing this come up a lot lately. Have you tried outerWidth()? http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: Before anything, make it more readable by assigning each width to a variable. It just looks sloppy and hard to read that way. Also, it would be awesome if you can provide a FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/